# TSQL Point of Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 4 tables in a query.
Table A
Table B
Table C
Table D.

Table D contains look up values relating to Table B.
I have structured the query as follows:

```
Select a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col1, b.Col2, c.Col1
from [Table A] a
inner join [Table C] c
    on c.key1= a.key1
    and c.key2 = 'static value'
inner join [Table B] b
    on b.key1 = a.key1
    and b.key2 = 'static value'
    **and b.key3 in (select d.key1
                   from [Table D] d)**
    and substring(b.key4, len(b.key4), 1) in ('static value 1', 'static value 2')
    and substring(b.key4, 1, len(b.key4)-1) in c.key1
```

So my problem appears on the join to [Table B].   Specifically, when joining b.key3 to the list of values.   It appears that SQL executes the query of Table D after the join is made because I get invalid results.   Now if I provide the 'In' the specific values the query of Table D would return.   It runs without a problem and yields valid results.

Can someone clarify how the execution of this query works as it relates to the total query and also a possible workaround if you have encountered this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you just want to check that b.key3 exists in [table d], you can work around this by using an inner join to table d and if there is a one-to-many relationship between this table and the others then use a group by.

```
    Select a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col1, b.Col2, c.Col1
    from [Table A] a
    inner join [Table C] c
        on c.key1= a.key1
    inner join [Table B] b
        on b.key1 = a.key1
    inner join [Table D] d
        ON  b.key3 = d.key1
    where c.key2 = 'static value' 
        and b.key2 = 'static value'
        and right(b.key4,1) in ('static value 1', 'static value 2')
        and substring(b.key4, 1, len(b.key4)-1) = c.key1
   group by a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col1, b.Col2, c.Col1
```

I have also moved your static variable checks to a WHERE clause and removed the SUBSTRING functions as you can also complete what you want using the RIGHT function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see what you did there which makes sense. However, I tried emplementing this and ran into the same issue.  What is happening is I get conversion errors of text to int when this line executes.  and substring(b.key4, 1, len(b.key4)-1) in c.key1.   c.key1 is definitly all integers.   b.key4 should be integers when the substring executes.   The query/join of the values in Table D should eliminate those values that muddy this up.   Valid values are 214y, 113q, 667y.   But for some reason, the join to Table B is not filtering out invalid values.   Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure I understand the issue you are having, I would check that you are casting your values when comparing different data types, also you could do the substrings in a CTE first and eliminate any values that are not INTs.